# Is there a way to create an ember-data model with a belongsTo association using the associated model's id?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the id of a model I know should exist, and I would like to create a record with a `belongsTo` association to this model. However, I would like to only provide the id when creating the association, rather than first query for the associated model. Is this possible?

This is what I would like to work (or some variant of it):

```
store.createRecord('person', {childId: '1', name: 'billybob'});
```

This is for a model defined as follows:

```
Person = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  child: DS.belongsTo('child'),
});
```

The guides suggest something like this:

```
store.createRecord('person', {child: child, name: 'billybob'});
```

Where `child` has already been fetched from the store at some point or is a newly created record.

I was hoping to then return the child side-loaded. This could avoid needing endpoints on the backend to deal directly with children, as they are always handled via the person endpoints.

Since we're only giving the backend the ID, it would need to fail if that record doesn't actually exist.

I've tried various permutations such as:

```
store.createRecord('person', {child: {id: '1'}, name: 'billybob'});
```

and have attempted to customize the model's serializer without success.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: From where exactly do you have the child id if you dont have it already loaded? If its in your store consider `peekRecord`.

Comment: It is the id provided in the dynamic segment of the URL, so if someone comes in from a link the model won't be loaded. In my particular case the ID of the association (child_id in my example) is for a model that is not user-specific, but the main model of the route (person's ID in my example) is user-specific. So if a user-specific instance to go with the general associated model doesn't exist, I want to create one and at the same time associate the non-user-specific model with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for you to go is to create the record with `store.push()` first. Then you either can use `store.unload` to remove the store from the record, or make sure that `adapter.shouldReloadRecord` returns `true` for this record so it will get loaded the next time you `find` it.